# Value does not fall within the expected range in Asynchronous Function

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, lync

I'm trying to sign in the Lync Client from code but am getting the runtime error `Value does not fall within the expected range`. The error occurs when I call the BeginSignIn method as shown below.

I don't know how to tell which value is causing the problem. I suspect it might be a problem with my Callback function, but if it is, I don't know what's wrong with it.

```vb
Dim _asyncState As Object() = {_client, ""}
Dim username As String = Me.txtUsername.Text
Dim userUri As String = Me.txtUserUri.Text
Dim password As String = Me.txtPassword.Text
_client.BeginSignIn(userUri, username, password, AddressOf signInCallback, _asyncState)

Public Sub signInCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
    If ar.IsCompleted = True Then
        Dim asyncState As Object() = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, Object())
        DirectCast(asyncState(0), LyncClient).EndSignIn(ar)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment so having to post as an answer, however I do have a lot of experience with the Lync Client SDKs and may be able to help with a little more information.

I think you are right in that the issue is probably the call back as Lync generally gives quite complete information in the instance of an exception and whilst your casting to an element in an array of objects is sound I suspect that.

Are you able to:-

1. Confirm that you hit the call back and where you get to
2. Ideally provide an exception stack

Thanks

Comment: No, the code never does hit the callback. It's failing on the 5th line of code, not inside the callback. I can provide an Exception Stack but so far it didn't seem very helpful.